# How to create a method for the datepicker element using selenium webdriver and java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Example Website: **http://www.phptravels.net/**

Date picker element:
[image]

Please find below the code which I used for the return date in the flight's module.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LaunchWebsite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\selenium-java-3.4.0\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.phptravels.net/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='#TRAVELPAYOUTS']")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("origin_name")));
        driver.findElement(By.name("origin_name")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("origin_name")).sendKeys("Delhi" + Keys.DOWN, Keys.TAB);
        driver.findElement(By.name("destination_name")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("destination_name")).sendKeys("Chandigarh" + Keys.DOWN, Keys.TAB);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//div[1]/table[@class='mewtwo-datepicker-table mewtwo-datepicker-table--normal-weekdays']"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//table[@class='mewtwo-datepicker-table mewtwo-datepicker-table--normal-weekdays']/tr[6]/td[@id='mewtwo-datepicker-2017-8-29']"))
                .click();
    }
}
```

This is selecting only the date 29th August.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Do you want us to write a code for you? Share the code snippet of what you have done for this so that we might help you.

Comment: Please check now. I have attached the code snippet.

Comment: Its only selecting 29th august because you have specified it in your code. `@id='mewtwo-datepicker-2017-8-29'`

Comment: Yes, Ashish.You are right but if I want to select some other dates apart from this, What should I do? Should I have to change the code again? Can we make this code as a Dynamic?

Comment: Where is the `function()` in your code to `put the date`?

Comment: @DebanjanB There is no function() in the code. I want a help from you guys to write a function for a date.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way will be to click on the input fields of Depart Date and Return Date then call this function with date as string in format yyyy-mm-dd

```
public void datePicker(String date){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mewtwo-datepicker-"+date+"']/div")).click();
    }
```

For example, if you want to select 31st August 2017 then call the function as

```
datePicker("2017-8-31");
```

Note that in the function I'm simply appending the xpath with your provided date.

Comment: Thank you, Ashish. This datePicker method only selects the date which is displaying on the web page. If I put the future dates which are not displayed on the web page then the code fails because the selenium is not able to find the element. Is it possible to set the next month or next year dates?

Comment: I dont think so, if those dates are not available in DOM then you cannot select them. Also, as far as I tried, I cannot manually feed the dates as input to the field. Hence I wont be able to help you find an answer for the future dates in this case.